# Filtering Markers Google Maps API V3

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I need your help with the following:

Currently I have a set of data in a Google Maps Spreadsheet. There are several things I need to filter this data on. For example the category and the type.

These are collected using JSON:

```
/** 
 * Called when JSON is loaded. Creates sidebar if param_sideBar is true.
 * Sorts rows if param_rankColumn is valid column. Iterates through worksheet rows, 
 * creating marker and sidebar entries for each row.
 * @param {JSON} json Worksheet feed
 */       
function cm_loadMapJSON(json) {

  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

  for (var i = 0; i < json.feed.entry.length; i++) {
    var entry = json.feed.entry[i];
    if(entry["gsx$" + param_latColumn]) {
      var lat = parseFloat(entry["gsx$" + param_latColumn].$t);
      var lng = parseFloat(entry["gsx$" + param_lngColumn].$t);
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
      var html = "<div class='infoscherm' style='font-size:12px'>";
      html += "<h2>" + entry["gsx$"+param_titleColumn].$t 
              + "</h2>";
      var label = entry["gsx$"+param_titleColumn].$t;
      if(entry["gsx$" + param_screenCategory]) {
        html += "<h3>" + "Screen Category/Purpose: " + "</h3>" + "<p>" + entry["gsx$"+param_screenCategory].$t + "</p>";
      }
      var screentype = entry["gsx$"+param_screenType].$t;
      if(entry["gsx$" + param_screenType]) {
        html +=  "<h3>" + "Screen Type: " + "</h3>" + "<p>" + entry["gsx$"+param_screenType].$t + "</p>";
      }
      if(entry["gsx$" + param_publicSpace]) {
        html += "<h3>" + "Type of Public Space: " + "</h3>" + "<p>" + entry["gsx$"+param_publicSpace].$t + "</p>";
      }
      var space = entry["gsx$"+param_publicSpace].$t;
      if(entry["gsx$" + param_screenInteraction]) {
        html += "<h3>" + "Type of interaction: " + "</h3>" + "<p>" + entry["gsx$"+param_screenInteraction].$t + "</p>";
      }
      if(entry["gsx$" + param_descriptionColumn]) {
        html += "<h3>" + "Description: " + "</h3>" + "<p>" + entry["gsx$"+param_descriptionColumn].$t + "</p>";
      }
      if(entry["gsx$" + param_screenAddress]) {
        html += "<h3>" + "Screen Location: " + "</h3>" + "<p>" + entry["gsx$"+param_screenAddress].$t + "</p>";
      }
      html += "</div>";

      // create the marker
      var marker = cm_createMarker(kaart,point,label,html,screentype,space);
      // cm_map.addOverlay(marker);
      cm_mapMarkers.push(marker);
      cm_mapHTMLS.push(html);
      bounds.extend(point); 
    }
  }

  kaart.fitBounds(bounds);
  kaart.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());
}
```

Now I want to be able to filter the markers located in the array. So only the markers fitting the filters are shown.

This function removes all the markers from the map. I was thinking of modyfying this function to create a good working dynamic filter for the markers. But I am not able to figure it out. Any Help? OR ideas maybe even other better working ways?

```
function clearOverlays() {
  if (cm_mapMarkers) {
    for (i in cm_mapMarkers) {
      cm_mapMarkers[i].setMap(null);
    }
  }
}
```

Thanx In advance

Answer (score 0):

You need either parallel arrays or a key-value array such as:

```
cm_mapMarkers.push({ point: marker, category: 'something' });
```

And then

```
function showSome(categoryName) {
  if (cm_mapMarkers) {
    for (var i = 0, marker; marker = cm_mapMarkers[++i]; ) {
      if(marker.category == categoryName){
        // do something with this marker
      }else{
        // do or do not with others.
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. If am not mistaken the markers and their values are currently in the array. What I need is for example when a checkbox with one of the categories is active only that category markers are shown. when 2 categories are checked those 2 category markers are shown. But besides category there is also screentype this also be added . For exampple 2 categories checked an creentype led is checked. then only those markers should be shown. I am sorry for not understanding your answer. Coding is not my strongest point :(

Comment: You need to convert your 'array of markers' to 'array of items containing information' where information is 3 properties: 'marker itself', 'category' and 'screentype' as per your comment.

Comment: I did the following: I replaced cm_mapMarkers.push(marker); with cm_mapMarkers.push({ point: marker, space: 'Park' }); and added the function showSome to the code. I execute the fucntion on a click event but nothing hapens :(

Comment: did u put something inside the IF ? changed .category to .space ?

Comment: yes I got this : function showSome(categoryName) {
  if (cm_mapMarkers) {
    for (var i = 0, marker; marker = cm_mapMarkers[++i]; ) {
      if(marker.space == categoryName){
        // do something with this marker
  marker.setVisible(true);
      }else{
        // do or do not with others.
  marker.setVisible(false);
      }
    }
  }
}

Comment: You should upload it to jsfiddle or similar.

Comment: @user1121078 you're not calling filterMarker() anywhere. I see triplicated code and also you're expecting a "category" parameter that you're never using inside the function.

Comment: I added some missing code sorry for the inconvienience! http://jsfiddle.net/tDYcX/6/